# AE data: impute missing end day and then insert rows from start day to end day

Tags: r

I have a following AE (adverse event) dataset.

```
ID  GR    STDY  ENDY
1    3     2     4
1    2     4     NA
1    1     7     9
2    1     1     NA
2    3     3     5
2    2     5     NA
```

When ENDY=NA, I want to impute using the STDY on the next row from the same subject, but set the same as STDY on the same row if it is the last entry for that subject, so the dataset will look like:

```
ID  GR    STDY  ENDY
1    3     2     4
1    2     4     7
1    1     7     9
2    1     1     3
2    3     3     5
2    2     5     5
```

Then i want to create a new dataset looking like this (for ID=1) which is essentially expanding the dataset to have one row for each day with the GR value carrying along starting from the STDY and ending at the ENDY.

```
ID  GR   DY  
1    3    2
1    3    3
1    3    4
1    2    4
1    2    5
1    2    6
1    2    7
1    1    7
1    1    8
1    1    9
```

Is there a smart way to handle this task? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), GR=c(3,2,1,1,3,2), STDY=c(2,4,7,1,3,5), ENDY=c(4,NA,9,NA,5,NA) );
df;
##   ID GR STDY ENDY
## 1  1  3    2    4
## 2  1  2    4   NA
## 3  1  1    7    9
## 4  2  1    1   NA
## 5  2  3    3    5
## 6  2  2    5   NA
df$ENDY <- unlist(by(df[,c('STDY','ENDY')],df$ID,function(x) { x$ENDY[is.na(x$ENDY)] <- c(x$STDY,x$STDY[nrow(x)])[which(is.na(x$ENDY))+1]; x$ENDY; }));
df;
##   ID GR STDY ENDY
## 1  1  3    2    4
## 2  1  2    4    7
## 3  1  1    7    9
## 4  2  1    1    3
## 5  2  3    3    5
## 6  2  2    5    5
df2 <- cbind(df[rep(1:nrow(df),df$ENDY-df$STDY+1),c('ID','GR')],DY=sequence(df$ENDY-df$STDY+1)+rep(df$STDY,df$ENDY-df$STDY+1)-1);
df2;
##     ID GR DY
## 1    1  3  2
## 1.1  1  3  3
## 1.2  1  3  4
## 2    1  2  4
## 2.1  1  2  5
## 2.2  1  2  6
## 2.3  1  2  7
## 3    1  1  7
## 3.1  1  1  8
## 3.2  1  1  9
## 4    2  1  1
## 4.1  2  1  2
## 4.2  2  1  3
## 5    2  3  3
## 5.1  2  3  4
## 5.2  2  3  5
## 6    2  2  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt.

```
mydf <- read.table(text = "ID  GR    STDY  ENDY
1    3     2     4
1    2     4     NA
1    1     7     9
2    1     1     NA
2    3     3     5
2    2     5     NA", header = T)

library(dplyr)

mydf$ENDY[is.na(mydf$ENDY)] <- mydf$STDY[which(mydf$ENDY %in% NA) + 1]

#  ID GR STDY ENDY
#1  1  3    2    4
#2  1  2    4    7
#3  1  1    7    9
#4  2  1    1    3
#5  2  3    3    5
#6  2  2    5   NA
```

Then, dealing with the irregular one.

```
mydf$ENDY[is.na(mydf$ENDY)] <- mydf$STDY[which(mydf$ENDY %in% NA)]

#  ID GR STDY ENDY
#1  1  3    2    4
#2  1  2    4    7
#3  1  1    7    9
#4  2  1    1    3
#5  2  3    3    5
#6  2  2    5    5
```

Using this new mydf, I did the following for your second question.

```
group_by(mydf, ID, GR) %>%
do(data.frame(DY = seq(.$STDY, .$ENDY)))

#   ID GR DY
#1   1  1  7
#2   1  1  8
#3   1  1  9
#4   1  2  4
#5   1  2  5
#6   1  2  6
#7   1  2  7
#8   1  3  2
#9   1  3  3
#10  1  3  4
#11  2  1  1
#12  2  1  2
#13  2  1  3
#14  2  2  5
#15  2  3  3
#16  2  3  4
#17  2  3  5
```

Comment: Thank you, Jazzurro. When i tried the code "mydf$ENDY[is.na(mydf$ENDY)] <- mydf$STDY[which(mydf$ENDY %in% NA) + 1]", the dataset didn't change for whatever the reason.  Thanks though!

Comment: @Ocean Thanks for your message. My code is working on my machine. Did you create `mydf` before you ran the code? One more thing, when you run the line you mentioned, R does not return the outcome automatically. You need to type `mydf` in R Console. Let me know if you still have the problem.